# Docker connection refused when started with -ti bash

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and  I tried to run the `linuxconfig/lemp-php7` image. Everything worked fine and I could access the nginx web server installed on the container. To run this image I used this command:
`sudo docker run linuxconfig/lemp-php7`

When I tried to run the image with the following command to gain access over the container through bash I couldn't connect to nginx and I got the `connection refused` error message. Command: `sudo docker run -ti linuxconfig/lemp-php7 bash`

I tried this several times so I'm pretty sure it's not any kind of coincidence.

Why does this happen? Is this a problem specific to this particular image or is this a general problem. And how can I gain access to the shell of the container and access the web server at the same time?

I'd really like to understand this behavior to improve my general understanding of docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker run` runs the specified command **instead** of what that container would normally run.  In your case, it [appears to be](https://github.com/linuxconfig/lemp-php7/blob/master/Dockerfile) `supervisord`, which presumably in turn runs the web server.  So you're preventing any of that from happening.

My preferred method (except in cases where I'm trying to debug cases where the container won't even start properly) is to do the following **after** running the container normally:

```
docker exec -i -t $CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

Comment: So basically supervisor is used to execute multiple programs when the container launches. And the command after run (bash for example) overwrites the `CMD ["supervisord"]`?