# Docker run not working with latest commands

Tags: docker

I'm using two commands to create a container

1. `sudo docker container run  --name  webserver1  --publish 80:80 nginx`
2. `sudo docker container run -it --name webserver2 --publish 81:80 nginx /bin/bash`

The first command works correctly, including when accessed via localhost at 127.0.0.1:80. However, when I use the second command with `/bin/bash`, it successfully creates and starts the container, but the Nginx server on localhost does not work. Is there something wrong with the second command?

How to make the second command work? Or is there any alternative command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker connection refused when started with -ti bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287681/docker-connection-refused-when-started-with-ti-bash)

Answer (score 1):

The second container replaces the default command to run (an nginx server) with `/bin/bash`. Bash is a shell, not an nginx server, and is not listening for http requests on port 80. Therefore any requests to localhost port 81 will be forwarded to the container port 80 and refused by the container since there's no application listening on that port.

To make the second command start an nginx server, remove the `/bin/bash` override of the command to run in the container.